# I can't see Airpush Ads on my app

Tags: android, airpush

I have an approved app but I can't see banner ads on my screen. What cause this issue?

```
  05-10 14:50:58.579: I/BunSDK(20986): Status code: 200
    05-10 14:50:58.584: I/BunMraid(20986): Ad json:{"status":120,"count":0,"url":"","message":"App is disapproved. Please reach out to Airpush support"}
    05-10 14:50:58.584: I/BunMraid(20986): No banner type present in response.
```

Comment: don't bother - AirPush is a scam - they don't pay!!!

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the log, your app isn't actually approved:

```
"message":"App is disapproved. Please reach out to Airpush support"
```

I suggest you checking that your app is really approved and all app data is filled correctly.

Comment: On Airpush's dasboard it seen as approved. Also in test mode I can see ads.

Comment: I also wrote "checking that [...] app app data is filled correctly". I don't know how airpush works but I'm pretty sure it used some codes and names, so check those.